# Variadic functions addition in c++ with constrained types

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-functions

My goal is to do a simple addition of *any* number of parameters as long as they are of the following types -

1. integer (e.g. 123)
2. string represented as integer (e.g. "123")

If they are of some other type, I ignore them.

**Approach**

1. I'm using a variadic function approach.
2. Within the function, I check for type. If the type is *int*, then I add recursively. Else, I ignore the argument, and recur on further arguments.

Here's what I think the code looks like --

```
// BASE
template <typename T>
int func(T t)
{
    string type= typeid(t).name();
    if (type==typeid(int).name())
        return stoi(t);
    else if (type==typeid(const char*).name())
        return atoi(t);
    else
        return 0;
}
// RECUR
template<typename T, typename... Args>
int func(T t, Args... args) // recursive variadic function
{
    string type = typeid(t).name();
    if (type==typeid(int).name()){
        int sum = t;
        return sum+func(args...);
    }
    else
        return func(args...);

}

// MAIN
int main()
{
    // All testing here in MAIN.


    // [2]
    int funcres = func('a',1, 2.5000,"123");
    cout << funcres << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This gives me the expected answer: **124.**

However, 
I made following observations which tell me that my code is not fail-safe.

- Why is stoi required in this line of the base function?

  if (type==typeid(int).name())
              return stoi(t);

If I do not do this and call just `return t`, I get an error when I call my function.

```
Cannot initialize return object of type 'int' with an lvalue of type 'const char *'
```

This doesn't make sense to me when I've already specified that return the integer if the type is integer.

- Even after I do `return stoi(t)` (which I don't understand why is required in the first place), and `return atoi(t)` if the type is `const char*` then inserting "japan" or "123" *at the beginning* or *in the middle* in the template arg list [for.e.g `func(1,2,2.5000,"123",12);`] causes the code to complain at this point.

  int sum = t;

The error is same as above.

```
Cannot initialize return object of type 'int' with an lvalue of type 'const char *'
```

- Is using variadic function the best way or are there alternatives?
- If it's the best way (it seems so to me since I need any number of parameters and any type of parameters to be considered for adding), what am I doing wrong?

Comment: By using `typeid`, you're taking something that could be done at compile-time (comparing types). By using `name`, you're not guaranteeing that they're actually the same type (different types can give the same result for `name`). And of course the compiler will complain when you do a runtime branch and then try to use the variable in a way that only that type can be used at compile-time (overload resolution etc.). `int` also isn't the only integer type. What about `long int`? `unsigned int`? `char` is technically an integral type, so if you generalize, it has to be excluded. `signed char`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overloading is one possibility.  You could also do it with some template magic.  This has the advantage, that the list over which you are summing is pruned at compile time from all incompatible types (except the last element, which is substituted by 0 if it is no match).

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>


template < typename T >
struct is_const_char : std::false_type {};
template < >
struct is_const_char < const char * > : std::true_type {};

template < typename T >
struct is_int : std::false_type {};
template < >
struct is_int < int > : std::true_type {};


// Break condition
template < typename T >
typename std::enable_if<is_int<T>::value, int>::type
sum(T t)
{
  return t;
}

template < typename T >
typename std::enable_if<is_const_char<T>::value, int>::type
sum(T t)
{
  return std::stoi(t);
}

template < typename T >
typename std::enable_if<!is_int<T>::value && !is_const_char<T>::value, int>::type
sum(T)
{
  return 0;
}


// Forward declarations
template < typename T, typename ... Args >
typename std::enable_if<is_const_char<T>::value, int>::type
sum(T, Args ...);

template < typename T, typename ... Args >
typename std::enable_if<is_int<T>::value, int>::type
sum(T, Args ...);

// Recursions
template < typename T, typename ... Args >
typename std::enable_if<!is_int<T>::value && !is_const_char<T>::value, int>::type
sum(T, Args ... args)
{
  return sum(args...);
}

template < typename T, typename ... Args >
typename std::enable_if<is_int<T>::value, int>::type
sum(T t, Args ... args)
{
  return t + sum(args...);
}

template < typename T, typename ... Args >
typename std::enable_if<is_const_char<T>::value, int>::type
sum(T t, Args ... args)
{
  return std::stoi(t) + sum(args...);
}


// Test it
int main()
{
  assert( sum('a', 1, 2, 3, "123", 4, 5) == 138 );
  assert( sum('a',1, 2.5000,"123") == 124 );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ templates are resolved statically, meaning that substituting the parameters has to work for all substitutions, even those which are unreachable at runtime. However by using overloads with a helper function instead of RTTI we can handle the conversion a lot more cleanly:

```
template<class T>
int forceInt(T arg) { return 0; }

int forceInt(int arg) { return arg; }

int forceInt(std::string arg) { return std::stoi(arg); }

int forceInt(const char * arg) { return std::stoi(arg); }
```

With this helper function you can do a simple recursive sum:

```
int func() { return 0; }

template<typename T, typename... Args>
int func(T t, Args... args) // recursive variadic function
{

        return forceInt(t) + func(args...);
}
```

This can also be expanded to handle any integer type. By using SFINAE on the general overload to restrict it to non-integer types, this causes the int overload to become prefered for integral types. However char is integral so we also need to add a char overload of 0 if you don't want that to be implicitly converted to an int:

```
template<class T, class U = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
int forceInt(T arg) { return 0; }

int forceInt(char arg) {return 0;}
```

Comment: Interesting how you specialized `forceInt` instead of providing overloads, but provided an overload of `func` instead of specializing it.

Comment: Yeh, forgot that concrete overloads are chosen over templates if available. Overloads are a lot cleaner.

Comment: Exploiting the overload resolution also has zero runtime cost.